# How to read json file and store value to some variable in shell script

Tags: json, linux, shell, scripting, devops

```
{"status":
    {"reqStatus":"SUCCESS",
            "credentials":"R3DMPF8VIAKG6xLa5vOlp7kqmqE.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABxXVVhKZkJhMmVOL1ZJQWhRUTBYTGY1V2w2TjA9AAR0eXBlAANDVFMAAlMx*****..*",
                    "msgs":[{"msgCode":"ECMSE103",
                            "msgText":"User %A1% was authenticated successfully.",
                            "msgValues":["Tnt_PDU-CD_N53-vPOD4_EO1"]}]
    }
}
```

I have this json file in my directory and I just want to read this json file and have ***credentials***, I just want to store this key value in variable while running shell script code.

Answer (score 2):

First,  I recommend you format your JSON using a JSON formatter like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com.

Now, let's consider the file `test.json` which contains your JSON data.

```
╰─$ cat test.json
{
   "status":{
      "reqStatus":"SUCCESS",

"credentials":"R3DMPF8VIAKG6xLa5vOlp7kqmqE.AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABxXVVhKZkJhMmVOL1ZJQWhRUTBYTGY1V2w2TjA9AAR0eXBlAANDVFMAAlMx**..*",
      "msgs":[
         {
            "msgCode":"ECMSE103",
            "msgText":"User %A1% was authenticated successfully.",
            "msgValues":[
               "Tnt_PDU-CD_N53-vPOD4_EO1"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

To parse this JSON using bash, we can use the tool `jq`, which you can install by running, for example in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Once the tools is available, you can run the following to get the Credentials field:

```
CREDENTIALS=$(cat test.json | jq -r ".status.credentials")
```

To validate so, run:

```
╰─$ echo $CREDENTIALS
R3DMPF8VIAKG6xLa5vOlp7kqmqE.AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABxXVVhKZkJhMmVOL1ZJQWhRUTBYTGY1V2w2TjA9AAR0eXBlAANDVFMAAlMx**..*
```

Comment: This is great Rashad Zhran

Answer (score 0):

```
CREDENTIALS=$(awk -F\" '/credentials/ {print $4}' file.json)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FS`, `OFS` and `NF` to do all the hard-work, since only matching row will have `NF = 3` while other non-empty rows will either be 1 or 2 :

```
 input : 

 {"status":
    {"reqStatus":"SUCCESS",
            "credentials":"R3DMPF8VIAKG6xLa5vOlp7kqmqE.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABxXVVhKZkJhMmVOL1ZJQWhRUTBYTGY1V2w2TjA9AAR0eXBlAANDVFMAAlMx*****..*",
                    "msgs":[{"msgCode":"ECMSE103",
                            "msgText":"User %A1% was authenticated successfully.",
                            "msgValues":["Tnt_PDU-CD_N53-vPOD4_EO1"]}]
    }
}

 command :

  mawk 'NF*=2<NF' FS='^.*["]credentials["][ \t]*[:][ \t]*["]|["].*$' OFS= 

 output :

R3DMPF8VIAKG6xLa5vOlp7kqmqE.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABxXVVhKZkJhMmVOL1ZJQWhRUTBYTGY1V2w2TjA9AAR0eXBlAANDVFMAAlMx*****..*
```

Answer (score 0):

With `jq` + `read` and process substitution or command substitution

```
read var < <(jq '.status.credentials' file.json);
# or
var=$(jq '.status.credentials' file.json);
# output
echo $var
"R3DMPF8VIAKG6xLa5vOlp7kqmqE.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABxXVVhKZkJhMmVOL1ZJQWhRUTBYTGY1V2w2TjA9AAR0eXBlAANDVFMAAlMx*****..*"
```